# Could not load file or assembly 'JavaScript.Net.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, javascript.net

All,

I am getting this error：

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   JavaScript.Net.dll or one of its dependencies.

**From:**

https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net  , get test source.

**Run:**

win7，x64 ; vc++ 2008 to vc++ 2015, run error computer with net45.2,  run success computer with most all net (it is a development computer).

**Problem:**

Use fuslogvw.exe to get the msg, but I can't get the problem.

Best wishes.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "get test source"?  How did you acquire and build Javascript.Net?

Comment: Does this problem occur on your development machine, or elsewhere?  If elsewhere, which DLLs are you distributing?